# Using Intent without getApplicationContext()

Tags: android-intent, view

Hey Guys have a small problem, I have a `ListView` and a class that is a listener for this `ListView`. On click the `ListView` should pass the link in the `ListView` in an intent to another activity which will open the link in a `WebView`.

The problem is that when I try to use `getApplicationContext()` to start the intent the program crashes. Here is the code of the listener for the `ListView` below.

```
public class ListListener extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

    List<RssItem> listItems;
    Activity activity;

    /** We will set those references in our constructor.*/
    public ListListener(List<RssItem> aListItems, Activity anActivity) {
        listItems = aListItems;
        activity  = anActivity;
    }

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        String Link = listItems.get(pos).getLink();
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),WebView.class);
        i.putExtra("newLink", Link);
        activity.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

I've tried several things in the `onItemClick` that didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried using `activity` instead of `getApplicationContext()`? Anyway, it's a good practice to post the Logcat in case your app crashes.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    final Intent intent = new Intent(this, items[position].getActivity());
    startActivityForResult(intent, position);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but looking at this code, how do i start the WebView activity like i did in this line:  Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),WebView.class);